# Openpyxl save error "Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'bool'"

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter, openpyxl

I am trying to automate an Excel dashboard using Openpyxl v2.3.2 . I'm using a jupyter notebook (Anaconda 4.11) to run my code using Python 2.7.

I have an existing spreadsheet that I am trying to alter and then save. After some playing around I noticed it wasn't saving properly, so I took each sheet (one by one) into a fresh spreadsheet and tried saving it again. I noticed it was throwing the same error every time. The code I'm running is below (pretty simple)

```
import openpyxl as xl
TVXL = xl.load_workbook('Dashboard.xlsx')
TVXL.save('TVXL.xlsx')
```

Which returns the error

```
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'bool'
```

The most pertinent part of the full error message is:

```
C:\Users\v7736101\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\styles.pyc in write_table(self)
 32         self._write_fonts()
 33         self._write_fills()
---> 34         self._write_borders()
 35 
 36         self._write_named_styles()

C:\Users\v7736101\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\styles.pyc in _write_borders(self)
 66         borders_node = SubElement(self._root, 'borders', count="%d" % len(self.wb._borders))
 67         for border in self.wb._borders:
---> 68             borders_node.append(border.to_tree())
 69 
 70     def _write_named_styles(self):

C:\Users\v7736101\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.pyc in to_tree(self, tagname, idx, namespace)
 97                 del attrs[key]
 98 
---> 99         el = Element(tagname, attrs)
100 
101         for child_tag in self.__elements__:

lxml.etree.pyx in lxml.etree.Element (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:75395)()

apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._makeElement (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:16379)()

apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._makeElement (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:16236)()

apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._initNodeAttributes (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:18647)()

apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._addAttributeToNode (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:18846)()

apihelpers.pxi in lxml.etree._utf8 (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:30113)()

TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'bool'
```

The top error indicates to me that there is something wrong (or incompatible) with the border formatting but after playing around with some of the border styles I can't seem to fix it.

Here's a screenshot of the document I'm trying to save.

[screenshot of daily calls that feeds into the dashboard, one of 5 similar tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iU17.jpg)

Other information:

1. Dashboard.xlsx is unaffected (presumably as it is garbage collected if I restart the kernel without saving the changes) but the output doc TVXL.xlsx is corrupted and cannot be opened.
2. the error that is thrown is in serialisable.pyc but I can't tell from reading it what that function does or how it feeds through.
3. in the screenshot of my spreadsheet I have added dummy data as it's sensitive information

Hopefully you can help me fix this as it's the first real demonstration of how powerful python is within my area of the business.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try updating to 2.3.5 at least but I suspect there is a problem with styles in the file you're reading. If the problem persists with a new version then I would suggest you create a bug on the openpyxl bugtracker and include a sample dashboard file.

Comment: I think that that version is the latest available for Anaconda, I will take you advice and try with pure python before I submit a bug. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same error. Found out the problem is that there are a couple special characters or formats in excel which are not recognized by openpyxl. These are pretty uncommon attributes though, for example, in my excel it was a box with a diagonal boarder causing the problem